# Does compiling a program in Visual Studio (Windows Forms, VB.NET) leave a MAC address in the executable?

Tags: programming

I am not making an installer. It is just a form as a portable .exe file. Asking because it's generating links to an external Web API (not mine) that is an openload crawler. Although technically legal (streaming is also legal in my country) I still do not want to be linked to it in any way if it spreads further than my circle of friends. It's very useful if you're as lazy as me and hate ads/malware.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if you worry about it, why not compile in a virtual machine?

Comment: While the MAC address specifically might not be included, there could be other clues to your identity in the compiled package, such as a directory path with your username. If you're concerned about someone being able to find a physical location for your computer from the code, that's unlikely, but if you're worried about someone with access to your machine being able to tie the code to it, then you may need to think more generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to give you a definitive answer to this. The short answer: **it is unlikely that your MAC (or IP) address will be included in any executable you compile for the purpose you described,** unless you intentionally included it.

In order to be more certain, you would have to do a code review of every dependency you have used in your project, which could be a pretty big job.

As pointed out by [Z.T.](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/70830/z-t) in a comment to your question, though, one way to make it *much* less likely would be to compile your code in a virtual machine. Exactly how to do that is beyond the scope of an answer to this question; [this guide](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-set-up-a-virtual-machine-for-free-1828969527) should be adequate to get a virtual machine of Windows running under Windows.